# Store data from database to json file

Tags: python, json, database

So I created database, store some data to table and want import it to JSON format to vizualize it with some JS script. But when Im trying to write it to JSON I get

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

There is the code:

```
from PyBambooHR import PyBambooHR
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import json


Base = declarative_base()


class EmployeeData(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'employee_data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120))
    department = Column(String(120))
    jobTitle = Column(String(120))
    email = Column(String(120))

    def __init__(self, name, department, jobTitle, email):
        self.name = name
        self.department = department
        self.jobTitle = jobTitle
        self.email = email


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///employee_db.db')

connection = engine.connect()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


bamboo = PyBambooHR(subdomain='domain', api_key='apikey')

session_factory = sessionmaker(engine)
session = session_factory()

employees = bamboo.get_employee_directory()
employees_list = [EmployeeData(name=item['displayName'], department=item['department'], jobTitle=item['jobTitle'], email=item['workEmail']) for item in employees]

avoid_duplicates = list(connection.execute('select * from employee_data'))

for i in employees_list:
    if i.name not in [j[1] for j in avoid_duplicates]:
        session.add(i)

session.commit()
session.close()
connection.close()

with open('employee_db.db', 'rb') as input_file:
    content = json.load(input_file)
with open('employee_data.json', 'wb') as output_file:
    json.dump(content,output_file, indent=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking encoding of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is the working code if someone need it somehow to work with BambooHR

> url = 'request-with-api-key' must looks like 
>    '[https://**API_KEY**@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/**SUBDOMAIN**/v1/employees/directory](https://__API_KEY__@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/__SUBDOMAIN__/v1/employees/directory)'
>
> You can get your API key from BambooHR by clicking on yours photo in the right corner and click API Keys

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json, requests


Base = declarative_base()


class EmployeeData(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'employee_data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120))
    department = Column(String(120))
    jobTitle = Column(String(120))
    email = Column(String(120))

    def __init__(self, name, department, jobTitle, email):
        self.name = name
        self.department = department
        self.jobTitle = jobTitle
        self.email = email


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///employee_db.db')

connection = engine.connect()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


url = 'request-with-api-key'
r = requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)

employees = []
for emp in root.iter('employee'):
        name_photo = {'name': '', 'department': '', 'jobTitle': '', 'email': ''}
        for data in emp.iter('field'):
            if data.attrib['id'] == 'displayName':
                name_photo['name'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'department':
                name_photo['department'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'jobTitle':
                name_photo['jobTitle'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'workEmail':
                name_photo['email'] = data.text
            else:
                continue
        employees.append(name_photo)

session_factory = sessionmaker(engine)
session = session_factory()

employees_list = [EmployeeData(name=item['name'], department=item['department'], jobTitle=item['jobTitle'], email=item['email']) for item in employees]
avoid_duplicates = list(connection.execute('select * from employee_data'))

for i in employees_list:
    if i.name not in [j[1] for j in avoid_duplicates]:
        session.add(i)

session.commit()

write_list = [{'name': i[1], 'department': i[2], 'jobTitle': i[3], 'email': i[4]} for i in list(connection.execute('select * from employee_data'))]

session.close()
connection.close()

with open('employee_data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(write_list, file)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, seems obvious:

```
with open('employee_db.db', 'rb') as input_file:
    content = json.load(input_file)
```

Where did you get the baroque idea that an sqlite database would be in json format?

Comment: thought that it could use strings from database to fill json

Comment: Oh yes my bad, obviously a json parser should know how to read any arbitrary binary format and turn it into just the exact json output format you had in mind...